# Android lint - simply returns "does not exist"

Tags: android, android-lint

I have Android tools r16 installed on a Win7 machine. I have the tools folder in my path. I can run "lint" and the command executes, giving me help on the command line parameters.

I then navigate to a project folder, and type:

```
> lint .
```

I expected it to run against the project in the current folder, but it seems to run against a project called SdkController, which is inside the Android tools folder.

Assuming I need to explicitly provide the full path to the project I tried again with this:

```
> lint c:\...\android\projectX\source\
```

I just get "does not exist". If I take the exact same path and CD to it, I am taken to that folder. The path I'm specifying definitely exists. What is it that "does not exist"?

I'm probably missing something very obvious, but can anyone explain to me how to run Android lint on Windows without this error?

Comment: is the \...\ \Program Files\ by any chance? Or is your SDK with lint in \program files\ ?

Comment: Neither lint nor the app are under Program Files.

Comment: Sorry or something with a space in it, like /Documents and Settings/ ?

Comment: You are spot on. The problem is a space in the pathname. Even with quotations it doesn't work, but I renamed the folder, and now it works just fine. Feel free to add your suggestion as an answer and I'll mark it as the solution. Thx.

Comment: Glad it was that! :-) Answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah it's probably that you have a space in your folder path :-) like:

/Documents and Settings/

every new install I do or watch someone do I always recommend. Easy:

C:/AndroidSDK/

Comment: Are you aware of any way to specify that lint use the current folder, rather than specifying a fully-qualified path name?

Comment: Nope only way I can think is to move lint to that folder